# How to control scientific notation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib, formatting

This is my data frame I'm trying to plot:

```py
my_dic = {'stats': {'apr': 23083904, 'may': 16786816, 'june': 26197936}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dic)
```

This is how I plot it:

```py
ax = my_df['stats'].plot(kind='bar',  legend=False)
ax.set_xlabel("Month", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Stats", fontsize=12)
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False) #AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.
plt.show()
```

The plot:

[image]

I'd like to control the scientific notation. I tried to suppress it by this line as was suggested in other questions `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` but I get this error back -

```
AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter
```

Ideally, I'd like to show my data in (mln).

Comment: Did you find out what it was you did that made the `AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter` message disappear?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye it’s been a while but if you’re still interested, the error was because x-axis tick labels were not numbers. I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75796438/19123103) elaborating on it. As for OP, looks like they solved their problem by not using `ticklabel_format` at all (their answer below).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding this line helps to get numbers in a plain format but with ',' which looks much nicer:

```
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

[image]

And then I can use `int(x)/` to convert to million or thousand as I wish:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if this works for logarithmic plots? It throws no errors for me but will not format any of the numbers.

Answer (score 21):

Since you already using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

[image]

Comment: hi, I've just tried this for a subplot (1,2) and it works for the second plot (ax[1]) but not for the first plot ax[0].  any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're here wondering why you got the error,

```
AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter
```

then you got the error because as the error says, `ticklabel_format` only works with `ScalarFormatter` (which formats tick values as numbers), but some tick labels of your plot are not numbers.

###### 1. Check if the plot has minor ticks that need to be formatted

A common way this error might occur is when you want to format the ticklabels of a plot with two levels of ticks (major and minor) where the major ticks are not scalars. A common way this happens is when a bar plot is plotted with log scale. The easiest way to solve the error is to ditch `ticklabel_format` and use `ScalarFormatter` on both levels of ticks instead.

```py
plt.bar([1,2], [1000, 2000], log=True)

plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')             # <---- error


from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter()) 
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter());   # <---- OK
```

###### 2. Check if the plot has minor ticks that need to be formatted

Another way is when one axis tick labels are not scalars (as in the OP). In the OP, x-axis tick labels are not numbers so the error was raised (by default both axes are flagged). Specifying `axis='y'` in `ticklabel_format` solves the error.

```py
ax = my_df['stats'].plot(kind='bar', legend=False, xlabel='Month', ylabel='Stats', rot=0)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', scilimits=(0,10))   # <--- no error
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', scilimits=(0,10))   # <--- error because ticklabels are strings
```

Also if the y-ticklabels need a thousands separator comma, then `set_yticks()` could be used to change it as such.

```py
ax = my_df['stats'].plot(kind='bar', legend=False, xlabel='Month', ylabel='Stats', rot=0)
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[:-1], [f"{int(x):,}" for x in ax.get_yticks()[:-1]]);
```

[image: res]