# Matplotlib logarithmic scale displayed as integers workaround does not work with a specified scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

`Matplotlib` inherently sets logarithmic scales to use scientific notation. If you want to avoid this you have to use a workaround such as the following minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(100,110)
y=np.arange(10)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, squeeze=False)
axes = axes[0]
axes[0].plot(x,y)
axes[1].plot(x,y)
for ax in axes:
     ax.set_yscale('log')
     ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

This works fine under all cases and has been shown as a solution as under many questions such as [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735745/how-to-control-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21920233)

I have used this solution fine before. However there is another issue that I have not seen discussed. If you want to set a `ax.ylim(...)` this work around stops working

Consider the following example (note the new line `ax.set_ylim(0,10)`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(100,110)
y=np.arange(10)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, squeeze=False)
axes = axes[0]
axes[0].plot(x,y)
axes[1].plot(x,y)
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image: Error]

### This is no longer the desired output.

Is there anyway to avoid this weird interaction?

Comment: Your Example 2 link is blank. Try clicking it

Comment: @Bazingaa Will fix, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently using **only** `major_formatter` which only applies to the major ticks on your log scale. You need to additionally use `minor_formatter` in your second case because what you see as `2 x10^0`, `3 x 10^0` etc are the minor tick-labels the formatting of which has to be treated separately.

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter()) # <---- Added
```

[image]