# How do I convert axis from scientific notation to standard numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot some house price data so imagine in the 100,000 - 300,000 range, but my Y axis keeps defaulting to scientific notation.

```
reading.plot(kind='scatter', x='Transaction Date',y='Price Paid', alpha=0.1, c='green', ylim=(0,2000000))
```

Is there an extra variable I should be adding?

Thanks in advance!

Rich

[image: Scatterplot]

Comment: Welcome to SO Richard. If you are using mathplotlib then you can use a `ticklabel_format` `style=plain`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax =  plt.subplots()
reading.plot(kind='scatter', x='Transaction Date',y='Price Paid', alpha=0.1, c='green', ylim=(0,2000000), ax=ax)
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - just tried it and weirdly got this error?

AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter

Does this mean anything to you? 

Thanks again!

Comment: can you try using    plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y'), instead of ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
I don't know exactly the reason for the error you are getting (as I am not able to reproduce the error on sample data)

Comment: Also take a look at this question which mentions the same error you are getting: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735745/how-to-control-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib>

Comment: plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y') worked!  thank you so much! Is there a specific reason to why it's doing this?